# AWS CodeDeploy Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy my code using AWS CodeDeploy.
My first deployment failed because of some typo in the appspec file.
After correcting the appspec file i tried to deploy it but this time it gave me the follwing error.

> The deployment failed because a specified file already exists at this location.

Why is it happening? Possible workaround except for beforeInstall script.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=690221

Comment: hey @Daniel it seems like beforeScript is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to appspec.yml

```
overwrite: true
```

It should be something like below.

```
- source: web
destination: /var/www/html/
overwrite: true
```

Comment: Hey Aamir, it worked. I had already done that but I wasn't including it inside source. Thanks, dude.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below troubleshooting link for this issue: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html#troubleshooting-same-files-different-app-name